# Dump and Restore data PostgreSQL from PC to Hosting(Server)

Tags: postgresql, restore, dump

I'm having trouble dumping data from PostgreSQL on my PC

When I upload / Restore to hosting via PHPPgAdmin only the table structure appears while the contents are not.

This is my Command for dump

```
pg_dump -h localhost -U postgres -c -f C:\pg\new2.sql siakad
```

Please check where the error

Comment: So how do you restore the dump?

Comment: Use PHPPgAdmin, just upload script from the dump

Answer (score 0):

Remove `-c` as it dumps a clean state of your database.  Instead it should be like this:

```
pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -f C:\pg\new2.sql siakad
```

or if you want to dump specific table:

```
pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -t tablename -f C:\pg\tablenew.sql siakad
```